# Issue with Drupal, get http://example.com 404 and favicon.ico missing

Tags: drupal, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I am trying to launch a Drupal container using ecs and connecting to a RDS MySQL instance for the database, using CloudFormation Templates in nested form.The nginx image is working fine but I am not so sure about drupal. The Instances works perfectly until the install part. But after which it provides this output.

Could really use some help.

[image]

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the ECS instances.
  VpcId:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    Description: Select a VPC that allows instances access to the Internet.
  SubnetId:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Description: Select at two subnets in your selected VPC.
  DesiredCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: '1'
    Description: Number of instances to launch in your ECS cluster.
  MaxSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: '1'
    Description: Maximum number of instances that can be launched in your ECS cluster.
  InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.medium
    AllowedValues:
      - t2.micro
      - t2.small
      - t2.medium
      - t2.large
      - m3.medium
      - m3.large
      - m3.xlarge
      - m3.2xlarge
      - m4.large
      - m4.xlarge
      - m4.2xlarge
      - m4.4xlarge
      - m4.10xlarge
      - c4.large
      - c4.xlarge
      - c4.2xlarge
      - c4.4xlarge
      - c4.8xlarge
      - c3.large
      - c3.xlarge
      - c3.2xlarge
      - c3.4xlarge
      - c3.8xlarge
      - r3.large
      - r3.xlarge
      - r3.2xlarge
      - r3.4xlarge
      - r3.8xlarge
      - i2.xlarge
      - i2.2xlarge
      - i2.4xlarge
      - i2.8xlarge
    ConstraintDescription: Please choose a valid instance type.
  DBInstanceID:
    Default: mydbinstance
    Description: My database instance
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '63'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: >-
      Must begin with a letter and must not end with a hyphen or contain two
      consecutive hyphens.
  DBName:
    Default: mydb
    Description: My database
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '64'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: Must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters.
  DBInstanceClass:
    Default: db.m5.large
    Description: DB instance class
    Type: String
    ConstraintDescription: Must select a valid DB instance type.
  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Default: '50'
    Description: The size of the database (GiB)
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '5'
    MaxValue: '1024'
    ConstraintDescription: must be between 20 and 65536 GiB.
  DBUsername:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Description: Username for MySQL database access
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '16'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters.
  DBPassword:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Description: Password MySQL database access
    Type: String
    MinLength: '8'
    MaxLength: '41'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: must contain only alphanumeric characters.
Mappings:
  AWSRegionToAMI:
    us-east-1:
      AMIID: ami-09bee01cc997a78a6
    us-east-2:
      AMIID: ami-0a9e12068cb98a01d
    us-west-1:
      AMIID: ami-0fa6c8d131a220017
    us-west-2:
      AMIID: ami-078c97cf1cefd1b38
    eu-west-1:
      AMIID: ami-0c9ef930279337028
    eu-central-1:
      AMIID: ami-065c1e34da68f2b02
    ap-northeast-1:
      AMIID: ami-02265963d1614d04d
    ap-southeast-1:
      AMIID: ami-0b68661b29b9e058c
    ap-southeast-2:
      AMIID: ami-00e4b147599c13588
    ap-south-1:
      AMIID: ami-036eaa870decb368d
Resources:
  cloudfrontdistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        #DefaultRootObject: 
        #CacheBehaviors:
          #- ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
            #TargetOrginId: vn2699
            #PathPattern: /*.php
            #LambdaFunctionAssociations:
            # - EventType: string-value
            #   LambdaFunctionARN: string-value
        Enabled: True
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          TargetOriginId: vn2699
          CachePolicyId: 4135ea2d-6df8-44a3-9df3-4b5a84be39ad
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
          #LambdaFunctionAssociations:
          # - EventType: string-value
          #   LambdaFunctionARN: string-value
        IPV6Enabled: False
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !GetAtt ECSALB.DNSName
            Id: vn2699
            CustomOriginConfig:
              HTTPPort: 80
              OriginKeepaliveTimeout: 5
              OriginProtocolPolicy: http-only
              OriginReadTimeout: 30
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: ECS-example
  ReactS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: reacts3vn2699
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
  S3accessPoint:
    Type: AWS::S3::AccessPoint
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref 'ReactS3Bucket'
      Name: reactaccesspointvn2699
      VpcConfiguration:
        VpcId: !Ref 'VpcId'
  ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    #DependsOn: ECSAutoScalingGroup
    #Properties:
      #CapacityProviders:
        #- Nse
  ECSCapacityProvider:
    Type: AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupProvider:
        AutoScalingGroupArn: !Ref ECSAutoScalingGroup
      Name: Nse
  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: DB Security Group
      VpcId: !Ref 'VpcId'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - FromPort: 3306
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 3306
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt EcsSecurityGroup.GroupId
        - FromPort: 3306
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 3306
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt BastionSecurityGroup.GroupId
  BastionSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: BastionHost security group
      VpcId: !Ref 'VpcId'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - FromPort: 22
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - FromPort: 3306
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 3306
          #SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  EcsSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: ECS Security Group
      VpcId: !Ref 'VpcId'
  EcsSecurityGroupHTTPinbound:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '80'
      ToPort: '80'
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  EcsSecurityGroupSQLInbound:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '3306'
      ToPort: '3306'
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId
  EcsSecurityGroupSSHinbound:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '22'
      ToPort: '22'
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  NestedStackDB:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    DependsOn:
      - EcsSecurityGroup
      - DBSecurityGroup
      - BastionSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: bucket-link
      Parameters:
        SecurityGroupBastion: !GetAtt BastionSecurityGroup.GroupId
        SecurityGroup: !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId
        DBInstanceID: !Ref DBInstanceID
        DBName: !Ref DBName
        DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBInstanceClass
        DBUsername: !Ref DBUsername
        DBPassword: !Ref DBPassword
        DBAllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
  EcsSecurityGroupALBports:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '31000'
      ToPort: '61000'
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
  EcsSecurityGroupDrupal:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '9000'
      ToPort: '9000'
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'

  CloudwatchLogsGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Join ['-', [ECSLogGroup, !Ref 'AWS::StackName']]
      RetentionInDays: 14 
  taskdefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: !Join ['', [!Ref 'AWS::StackName', -ecs-demo-app]]
      ExecutionRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::<accNo>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
      #TaskRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
      NetworkMode: bridge
      #RequiredCompatibilities:
        #- "EC2"
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: webserver
          Cpu: 256
          DependsOn:
            - Condition: "START"
              ContainerName: "drupal"
          #Essential: 'true'
          Image: nginx-drupal:latest 
          Memory: 512
          Hostname: webserver
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref 'CloudwatchLogsGroup'
              awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
              awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs-demo-app
          VolumesFrom:
            - SourceContainer: drupal
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 80
              HostPort: 80
        - Name: drupal
          Cpu: 256
          Essential: false
          Image: drupal:9.1.5-php8.0-fpm-alpine3.12
          Memory: 512
          Hostname: drupal
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref 'CloudwatchLogsGroup'
              awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
              awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs-demo-app
          MountPoints:
            - ContainerPath: /var/www/html
              SourceVolume: drupal-data
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 9000
      Volumes:
        - Name: drupal-data
  ECSALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    #DependsOn: service
    Properties:
      Name: ECSALB
      Scheme: internet-facing
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
      - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
        Value: '30'
      Subnets: !Ref 'SubnetId'
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup']
  ALBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn: ECSServiceRole
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'ECSTG'
        #RedirectConfig:
          #Protocol: "HTTP"
          #Host: "#{host}"
          #Path: "/#{path}"
          #Query: "#{query}"
          #Port: 80
          #StatusCode: "HTTP_302"
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref 'ECSALB'
      Port: '80'
      Protocol: HTTP
  ECSALBListenerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    DependsOn: ALBListener
    Properties:
      Actions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'ECSTG'
        #RedirectConfig:
          #Protocol: "HTTP"
          #Host: "#{host}"
          #Path: "/#{path}"
          #Query: "#{query}"
          #Port: 80
          #StatusCode: "HTTP_302"
      Conditions:
      - Field: path-pattern
        Values: [/]
      ListenerArn: !Ref 'ALBListener'
      Priority: 1
  ECSTG:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    DependsOn: ECSALB
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 80
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 60
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: 302
      Name: ECSTG
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: instance
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      VpcId: !Ref 'VpcId'
  ECSAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      #VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref 'SubnetId'
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - subnet-0c228c2e5e42708aa
        - subnet-0bf3fcea01d2dd0a4
        - subnet-0c6a01197480771b3
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref 'ContainerInstances'
      #LoadBalancerNames:
        #- ECSALB
      TargetGroupARNs: [!Ref 'ECSTG']
      MinSize: '1'
      MaxSize: !Ref 'MaxSize'
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref 'DesiredCapacity'
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT15M
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
        WillReplace: 'true'
  ContainerInstances:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      ImageId: !FindInMap [AWSRegionToAMI, !Ref 'AWS::Region', AMIID]
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup']
      InstanceType: !Ref 'InstanceType'
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref 'EC2InstanceProfile'
      KeyName: !Ref 'KeyName'
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          echo ECS_CLUSTER=${ECSCluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
          yum update -y
          yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
          #/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup --region ${AWS::Region}
          #sudo cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup --region ${AWS::Region}
  service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: 
      - ALBListener
      #- ECSAutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref 'ECSCluster'
      DesiredCount: '1'
      HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: 2147483647
      LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: webserver
        ContainerPort: '80'
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'ECSTG'
        #LoadBalancerName: !GetAtt ECSALB.LoadBalancerName
        #LoadBalancerName: ECSALB
      #NetworkConfiguration:
      #  AwsvpcConfiguration:
      #    AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
      #    SecurityGroups:
      #      - !Ref 'EcsSecurityGroup'
      #    Subnets: !Ref 'SubnetId'
      #ServiceName: Ecs
      Role: !Ref 'ECSServiceRole'
      TaskDefinition: !Ref 'taskdefinition'
  ECSServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ecs.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ecs-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ['elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer', 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets',
              'elasticloadbalancing:Describe*', 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer',
              'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets', 'ec2:Describe*', 'ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress']
            Resource: '*'
  ServiceScalingTarget:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    #DependsOn: service
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 3
      MinCapacity: 1
      ResourceId: !Join ['', [service/, !Ref 'ECSCluster', /, !GetAtt [service, Name]]]
      RoleARN: !GetAtt [AutoscalingRole, Arn]
      ScalableDimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount
      ServiceNamespace: ecs
  ServiceScalingPolicy:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: AStepPolicy
      PolicyType: StepScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref 'ServiceScalingTarget'
      StepScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        AdjustmentType: PercentChangeInCapacity
        Cooldown: 60
        MetricAggregationType: Average
        StepAdjustments:
        - MetricIntervalLowerBound: 0
          ScalingAdjustment: 200
  ALB500sAlarmScaleUp:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      EvaluationPeriods: '1'
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: '10'
      AlarmDescription: Alarm if our ALB generates too many HTTP 500s.
      Period: '60'
      AlarmActions: [!Ref 'ServiceScalingPolicy']
      Namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
      Dimensions:
        - Name: LoadBalancer
          Value: !GetAtt 
            - ECSALB
            - LoadBalancerFullName
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      MetricName: HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count
  EC2Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      #ManagedPolicyArns:
        #- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ec2.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ecs-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ['ecs:CreateCluster', 'ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance', 'ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint',
              'ecs:Poll', 'ecs:RegisterContainerInstance', 'ecs:StartTelemetrySession',
              'ecs:Submit*', 'logs:CreateLogStream', 'logs:PutLogEvents']
            Resource: '*'
  AutoscalingRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: service-autoscaling
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ['application-autoscaling:*', 'cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms', 'cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm',
              'ecs:DescribeServices', 'ecs:UpdateService']
            Resource: '*'
  EC2InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles: [!Ref 'EC2Role']
Outputs:
  ecsservice:
    Value: !Ref 'service'
  ecscluster:
    Value: !Ref 'ECSCluster'
  ECSALB:
    Description: Your ALB DNS URL
    Value: !Join ['', [!GetAtt [ECSALB, DNSName]]]
  taskdef:
    Value: !Ref 'taskdefinition'






AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  SecurityGroupBastion:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
  DBInstanceID:
    Default: mydbinstance
    Description: My database instance
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '63'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: >-
      Must begin with a letter and must not end with a hyphen or contain two
      consecutive hyphens.
  DBName:
    Default: mydb
    Description: My database
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '64'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: Must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters.
  DBInstanceClass:
    Default: db.m5.large
    Description: DB instance class
    Type: String
    ConstraintDescription: Must select a valid DB instance type.
  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Default: '50'
    Description: The size of the database (GiB)
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '5'
    MaxValue: '1024'
    ConstraintDescription: must be between 20 and 65536 GiB.
  DBUsername:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Description: Username for MySQL database access
    Type: String
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '16'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters.
  DBPassword:
    NoEcho: 'true'
    Description: Password MySQL database access
    Type: String
    MinLength: '8'
    MaxLength: '41'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: must contain only alphanumeric characters.
Resources:
  DrupalDB:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceID
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBInstanceClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      EngineVersion: 8.0.20
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroupDrupal
      #MonitoringInterval: '60'
      #MonitoringRoleArn: ''
      AllowMajorVersionUpgrade: true
      #AssociatedRoles: 
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 1
      #CopyTagsToSnapshot:
      #DBClusterIdentifier:
      #DBSecurityGroups:
      #KmsKeyId:
      MultiAZ: true
      Port: 3306
      #SourceDBInstanceIdentifier:
      #PubliclyAccessible:
      #SourceRegion:
      StorageType: standard
      VPCSecurityGroups: [!Ref SecurityGroup]
  DBSubnetGroupDrupal:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: 'For Drupal DB'
      DBSubnetGroupName: 'DrupalDB'
      SubnetIds:
        - subnet-01cc7a208ce068cd7
        - subnet-0ed0f1627396e1a96
        - subnet-0b38eb422f032ea76
  BastionHost:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties: 
      AvailabilityZone: ap-south-1a
      #BlockDeviceMappings:
      ImageId: ami-068d43a544160b7ef
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
          DeviceIndex: 0
          GroupSet:
            - !Ref SecurityGroupBastion
          SubnetId: subnet-0c228c2e5e42708aa
```

Comment: What are the logs saying (php, mysql, ..) ?

Comment: The php was throwing an exception with the message specified in the image. The MySQL seemed to run without issue.

Comment: Looks like an issue with your nginx config?  You suggest that it worked up until after the site was installed, which is a bit odd ... maybe you mean "install" as in the CloudFormation rather than Drupal?  Either way, take a look at https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/ (not forgetting that your php-fpm isn't a local socket, you'll need something like `proxy:fcgi://$APP_CONTAINER:$APP_PORT`).